# PyCharm typehinting

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have this code:

```
pile = get_pile()
pile.spawn(func1)
pile.spawn(func2)
(var1, var2) = list(pile)
# :type MyClass
var1.do_something()
```

So, variable `var1`, which is returned by `func1()` is an instance of class `MyClass`. How do I tell my PyCharm that? I've tried with the upper comment and also several other approaches, but it always says that the type is unknown and autocomplete doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck doing type hinting like this:

`""" :type: MyClass """`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the type hints syntax in the [online documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d102946e633).

[image: type hint]